# how to rewrite this this inline javascript with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup with inline javascript and would like to change it to Jquery. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<a title="823557" href="/PhotoGallery.asp?ProductCode=471823557" id="product_photo_zoom_url">
<img border="0" onload="vZoom.add(this, '/v/vspfiles/photos/471823557-2.jpg');"
alt="823557"
src="/v/vspfiles/photos/471823557-2T.jpg" id="product_photo"></a>
```

I guess I would need to use this?

```
$(function(){
<---- somecode---->
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function () {
   $("#product_photo").load(function (e) {
      vZoom.add(this, this.src.replace('T.', '.'));
   })
})();
```

If `$` doesn't work for some reason, this should also work. I incorporated Kranu's advice since that library most likely only needs the DOM loaded as a prerequisite, rather than the `load` event:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#product_photo").each(function () { // in case there is more than one 
        vZoom.add(this, this.src.replace('T.', '.'));
    });
});
```

Comment: unless it's a typo, the img src is different from the second parameter to the .add function

Comment: also need to string replace the `T.jpg` with `.jpg` in `this.src`

Comment: @davidsleeps: It's the same `src` - just with a T added at the end (I assume to show that it's a thumbnail. Notice it's a modified value of `this.src`. @MattSmith: It already does that.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, will test but it look like it will work!!!

Comment: @user357034: Does it tell you what is not a function? `$` is not a function?

Comment: The second code worked perfectly, couldn't get the first one to work though. Really don't need the each function but it didn't hurt.

Comment: @user357034: Yes, you probably have a conflict with another library or something. In the future, put any jQuery code that is dependent on the DOM in that function.

Comment: I do not have any other lib loaded, I changed the jquery(function($){ to $(function($){ with no problems. thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no need to put a separate bind event on the img because the `$(function() { })` waits until the body loads.

```
$(function(){
    vZoom.add(document.getElementById('product_photo'),'/v/vspfiles/photos/471823557-2.jpg');
});
```

Comment: This is kinda what i want except instead of the static link to the image I need to do a string replace as in the example from @Daniel from the src to the following xxxxxxx-2.jpg

Comment: Well I'm glad you at least acknowledged my answer. I do admit that the str_replace thing is good for portability.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but essentially you would remove the image from the HTML and dynamically load it using JS. Once loaded, you would inject it in the DOM and set the onload event.

```
var jsImg = new Image();
jsImg.onload = function(){
  vZoom.add(this,'/v/vspfiles/photos/471823557-2.jpg');
  var img = document.createElement('IMG');
  img.setAttribute('id','product_photo');
  img.setAttribute('alt','823557');
  img.setAttribute('src','/v/vspfiles/photos/471823557-2T.jpg');
  img.style.border = 'none';
  //inject image now in the DOM whereever you want.
};
jsImg.src = '/v/vspfiles/photos/471823557-2T.jpg';
```